# Can I transfer Destiny: Legendary Edition (Taken King) from PS3 to PS4?

Tags: ps3, ps4, destiny

I have Destiny: Legendary Edition (Taken King) code to unlock the expansions and the disc for PS3. I redeemed the expansions code to my PS4 and it said that the expansions are ready for download, but I can't download them.  I need to buy the Destiny: Legendary Edition (Taken King) for PS4 or should I buy the Destiny(Standard Edition, without DLC) for PS4  to be able to download the expansions?

Comment: Well transferring characters was recently announced along with the latest expansion but no details have been released yet

Comment: recently announced? This was available soooi long ago, I believe it may have even expired.

Answer (score 1):

The offer to upgrade from PS3 to PS4 (and Xbox 360 to Xbox One) expired a while ago. From [the Bungie forums](https://www.bungie.net/en-us/Forums/Post/102146271?sort=0&page=0&path=1):

> The Digital Upgrade program is only for purchasing a digital copy of Destiny for Xbox 360 or PS3, then moving to the appropriate next gen console. However, this offer expired on January 15th, 2015. The only license you can transfer between consoles now is for the Expansion Pass or The Dark Below content if purchased on Xbox 360 or PS3.